# Axios Vue.js table is not reflecting response data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a function which I am calling whenever a file is uploaded in order to refresh my table which holds the files.

The `response.data` is coming back with the correct data but my table is not reflecting it. Any idea what I could do in order to force update my table to show the new entries?

If I refresh the page, the data comes back correct.

```
function GetFileList(intID) {
    //$("#fileuploadstbl").empty();
         
    var ItemsVue = new Vue({
        el: '#fileUploadContent',
        data: {
            items: []
        },
        mounted: function () {
            var self = this;
    
            axios.get("getUploads.ashx")
                .then(response => {
                    self.items = response.data 
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err.status);
                    console.log(err.response.status);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err.status);
                });
        }
    });
    $("#fileUploadContent").show();
}
```

And this is how I bind my `<tr>`:

```
<tr 
    v-for="item in items" class="tddata" 
    v-bind:data-ID="item.ID" 
    v-bind:data-Uploadid="item.Uploadid"
>
    <td>{{item.Filename}}</td>
    <td 
        style="cursor: pointer;text-align:center;"  
        v-on:click="ViewFile(item.Filepath,item.Filename)"
    >
        View File
    </td>
    <td 
        style="cursor: pointer;text-align:center;"  
        v-on:click="DeleteFile(item.ID,item.guid,item.Filepath,item.Filename)"
    >
        View File
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.UploadedBy}}</td>          
</tr>
```

Comment: try an `index` and `key` for `v-for`

Comment: I have added this : v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.ID"

Still it didn't refresh my table.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: using `axios`, something similiar also happens to me in a different case: I mean, while `data` gets updated, the view still shows the same content, and I solved this resetting the array, then adding another API call in the same function (`watch`, etc. didn’t help here)

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically update for your case. Maybe you can check is your response.data save in your "items". If still cannot, maybe try to use the forceupdate function

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```

Comment: I thought so as well as the response.data comes back with the correct items but its just the table that is not updating and i have no console errors weird.

Seems like this table fileUploadContent is not updated with response.data 


I will try this and let you know.

thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
//HTML
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" v-bind="users_model">


//In your method
axios.get('sample-domain..com').then(response => {
   this.users = response.data.data
   this.users_model++
})
```